# X=sm.add_constant(X, prepend=True) is not working

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to get the beta and the error term from a linear regression(OLS) in python. I am stuck at the statement `X=sm.add_constant(X, prepend=True)`, which is returning an

> error:"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'add_constant'"

I already installed the **statsmodels** module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sm` is a defined object in `statsmodels`, you need to invoke it by `statsmodels.sm`, or using `from statsmodel import sm`, then you can invoke `sm` directly.

Comment: Thanks, I have "print sm.OLS(Y,X).fit().params" which prints the beta and the coefficient. What if I only want beta or only coefficint. How can I do that?

Comment: If Y and X are numpy arrays, then you need to use a slice to get specific parameters, `params[0]`, `params[1]`,... If Y and X are pandas Series and DataFrames or when using the formula, then the `params` will be a pandas Series and access is by name.

Answer (score 6):

Try importing statsmodel.api

`import statsmodels.api as sm`

Comment: My mistake was that I used "import statsmodels as sm"--using the above line fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try importing add_constant, for example:

```
from statsmodels.api import add_constant
```